# Managing width of a carousel-indicators

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use custom carousel-indicators. I want to use three divs for the indicators of col-md-4 class. My code is:

```
<div class="row carousel-indicators">
            <div style="background-color:red;" class="col-md-4" data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                First
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:green;" class="col-md-4" data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
                Second  
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:blue;" class="col-md-4" data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
                Third
            </div>
        </div>
```

But, it is not working properly. On clicking any of the tab, the div collapses.

[image: image screenshot here]

Please help me to solve this.

Edit 1:

The full code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row carousel-indicators">
                <div style="background-color:red;" class="col-md-4" data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                    First
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:green;" class="col-md-4" data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
                    Second  
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:blue;" class="col-md-4" data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
                    Third
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img style="width:100%;height:90%;" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-51-5668472285560832.2-hp.gif">
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img style="width:100%;height:90%;" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img style="width:100%;height:90%;" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code or create a demo of current setup?

Comment: I am creating a js fiddle

Comment: @ManojKumar I have edited the question. The fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/dmkzu8eL/ , which is not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the Carousel JS was appending the class of the buttons with `active` which overrides its width to 12px and height to 12px. Try the below code.

```
.carousel-indicators .col-md-4.active {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/dmkzu8eL/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You are close!  Since Bootstrap uses media queries, each particular class applies to a certain screen size.  Relevant part of Bootstrap documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

The above link describes behavior at each screen size. In your code, you only specify the `col-md-4` class; by adding `col-sm-4 col-lg-4`, you should cover all use cases.

Updated Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dmkzu8eL/2/

EDIT:  So, I misread the question initially.  Essentially, the `.active` class is appended to the carousel indicator corresponding to the active item in the carousel.  This class specifies a width, height, and margin in terms of `px`, which is why it appears to collapse. Using the following CSS, we can stop the div from collapsing fully and hiding the text within:

```
#homeCarousel .carousel-indicators div.active
{
width:initial;
height:initial;
margin:initial;
}
```

With that said, it doesn't stop the `.active` div from shrinking down to the size of the text contained within, as you still would like to indicate to the user the position of the carousel, correct?

Updated Fiddle #2:http://jsfiddle.net/dmkzu8eL/12/

Comment: Well, I don't think he wanted that. When you click on the any one of the 3 buttons, you can notice it is shrinking/disappearing.

Comment: @ManojKumar Oops, I misread the question, although I am unable to duplicate the issue using the Fiddle found in his comment.

Comment: fiddle is not working. I think specifying col-sm-4 will cover all higher classes.

Comment: @learner You are correct, although I was not experiencing that in the Fiddle.  I've always been explicit in my implementation of `col-*` personally, but it is (as per the documentation) unnecessary.

Comment: Fiddle is not working because you have loaded jQuery after Bootstrap JS :)

Comment: @ManojKumar I just clicked the Fiddle provided and updated it, so that's super weird that it decided to re-order the external libraries!

Comment: Nope, I think it was learner's fault :) You just forked the mistake ;)

Comment: Haha, this may very well be true :).  That said, I've updated my answer.  Not sure if it is 100% what OP was looking for, but it's definitely a start.